# How to conditionally select properties of a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm starting with PostgreSQL and can't find anything useful for me, here it goes:

I have a couple of tables, the main table has a property called "is_thing" which stores a boolean value. If it's true, i want to select some other properties from the table "thing", which may be null if "is_thing" is false. I can't figure out how to do it (I don't want to split it in different nested queries). The query i'm using returns everything, if "is_thing" is true. But returns absolutely nothing if it's false. In these cases, I still want the main table properties.

Here's an example of my query:

```
SELECT
    m.id
    , m.is_thing
    , m.color
    , t.volume
    , t.age
FROM
    main m
    JOIN
        thing t
        ON
            t.id = m.id
WHERE
    m.id = 1234
```

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
SELECT
    m.id
    , m.is_thing
    , m.color
    , t.volume
    , t.age
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN thing t
ON t.id = m.id
WHERE m.id = 1234;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, can't believe it's so simple. Thanks so much.